# iOS app Icon - how to?

Tags: ios

Can someone explain me or link - I have 512x512 icon but I have no idea what icons sizes I need to create and how to add them in to my iOS app. What sizes I need and how to add them, and for what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell: 57x57 for non-retina iPhone or iPod Touch, 114x114 for retina display, and 72x72 for iPad.

Comment: and now 144x144 for retina iPad.

Comment: This spec is outdated for iOS7 (now mandatory to adhere). See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

Answer (score 8):

The [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) has all you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Ive put all the images named correctly at the correct size into a github repo, so there can be no confusion.

https://github.com/FattusMannus/iOS-Development-Image-Placeholders

Just download them as a zip, edit them and copy them into your project

AH

Answer (score 0):

In the current 5.x xCode version you can use app icon set (AppIcon.appiconset). In the picture you can see where you can found it. Here is online tool, [Icons Master](http://imageresier-agrastas.rhcloud.com), which will take care how icons should be big naming convection as well. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Specific name doesn't matter's any more for ios icon. All you need is perfect size.

I have created this application which will provide you all the icons based on information provided [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html). Get the [application from here](https://github.com/rptwsthi/AlliOSIconsWithProperName), and follow the instructions in readme file to create all the required icons for iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Asset Catalog Creator Free](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/asset-catalog-creator-free/id866571115?mt=12) from iTunes. All you have to do is select a base image, and the program will create all required iOS icon sizes for you and place them neatly in an `.xcassets` file, which you can simply drag into Xcode without worrying about the sizes/resolutions of individual icons.

Answer (score 0):

Question was asked a while back but the answer changes from time to time. Here are a few web tools that are updated with the latest requirements and get the job done:

http://www.theappicon.com/ or 
https://resizeappicon.com/

Drag and drop the .xcassets folder that they return into your xcode assets catalog and it should populate your app icons as you need them.