# Adding Image for App Icon throws following message: "did not have any applicable content Xcode"

Tags: xcode, icons, launch

I am using Xcode 6.1.1 and IOS 8.1.2 and try to add images for my app's icon; using the App Icon Sources option in the  "App Icons and Launch images " in the Project General sheet.

Every time I upload images to match the required displayed Point size, I receive the following message from Xcode: `" Did not have any applicable content Xcode"`. For example, uploading a 60pt square picture for the "iPhone App IOS 7,8 60pts"

It results into a compilation error, every time.

How to solve this?

Comment: Tell us what the icon's size is, what the icon's name is, and what device its intended for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS app Icon - how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6848736/608639)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the problem has come from the fact that the imported image for the app icon didn't have the proper size. In Xcode, it depicts the Icon size in Pt, as 29pt 2x, 40pt 2x, 60pt 2x and 60pt 3x. However, it is not possible to identify the pixel size of the required image from the literature.

One trick is to import one image for each of this icon; and opening the warning list. It will tell you the expected size.

However, here is the size in pixel for the app icons:

- IPhone Spotlight - IOS 5,6 Settings, IOS 5-8 29pt 2x : 58 pixels
- IPhone Spotlight IOS 7,8 40pt 2x:  80 pixels
- IPhone App IOS 7,8 60pt 2x:  120 pixels
- IPhone App IOS 7,8 60pt 3x:  180 pixels

Hope it can help you should you be in similar trouble :)

Comment: *... however, it is not possible to identify the pixel size of the required image from the literature"* - huh? Apple's [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) is very clear. The document also talks about the naming requirements.

Comment: The Apple documentation table refers to the iPhone type. In Xcode 6.1.1, you need to provide images for IOS version. For example, IPhone App IOS 7,8 60pt". It does not match the documentation.